# remote Kernel not found while scheduling the notebook in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am new to the cloud and it's components. I am trying to schedule a notebook in vertex AI with remote kernel of dataproc. when the schdeuler invokes the notebook I get an error jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named remote-54f5982ba157bXXXXXXXXXX-python3. when I run it manually it's working fine. Any idea why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Executor, you need to define the JobType as Dataproc and define dataprocParameters accordingly.

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v1/ExecutionTemplate#JobType

When you use a Dataproc Kernel you are accessing remotely via a "Mixer Service" which combines both local Kernels and remote Dataproc kernels. When you execute the Notebook via executor, the executor job runs directly in Dataproc so you would need to specify that.
Currently Executor extension does not support this workflow.